# How to get a submenu in a dropdown menu in CoreUI React?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, core-ui

I am using CoreUI React Free version. Currently to implement a simple dropdown, this is what one needs to do

```
<CDropdown
      inNav
      className="c-header-nav-items mx-2"
      direction="down"
      >

      <CDropdownToggle className="c-header-nav-link" caret={false}>
        <div className="c-avatar">
          <CImg
            src={'avatars/user.jpg'}
            className="c-avatar-img"
            alt="admin@bootstrapmaster.com"
          />
        </div>
      </CDropdownToggle>

      <CDropdownMenu className="pt-0" placement="bottom-end">
        
        <CDropdownItem
          header
          tag="div"
          color="light"
          className="text-center"
        >
          <strong>Account</strong>
        </CDropdownItem>
         
         <CDropdownItem>
          <CIcon name="cil-user" className="mfe-2" />Profile
        </CDropdownItem>
        
        <CDropdownItem>
          <CIcon name="cil-settings" className="mfe-2" />
          Settings
        </CDropdownItem>

        <CDropdownItem>
          <CIcon name="cil-credit-card" className="mfe-2" />
          Payments
        </CDropdownItem>

        <CDropdownItem divider />
        <CDropdownItem> 
          <CIcon name="cil-lock-locked" className="mfe-2" />
          Logout
        </CDropdownItem>
      </CDropdownMenu>
</CDropdown>
```

This is how it looks like
[image]

Now I want to add a submenu to Settings such that on clicking `Settings`, another menu opens up to its left and I can click on it to choose appropriate item. Something like below

[image]

I looked up online for documentation regarding integrating submenu to a dropdown menu in CoreUI but couldn't find anything.

The closest I could get was doing something like this to the `Settings` part

```
<CDropdownItem>
          <CIcon name="cil-settings" className="mfe-2" />
          Settings
          <CDropdownMenu>
            <CDropdownItem>
                Submenu Item 1
            </CDropdownItem>
            <CDropdownItem>
                Submenu Item 2
            </CDropdownItem>
          </CDropdownMenu>
 </CDropdownItem>
```

So now it looks like below

[image]

But as you can see, the submenu is not aligned and it is visible by default against the intended behaviour of clicking the `Settings` first and then the submenu should appear.

Is there any way CoreUI supports submenu in a dropdown menu? Or is there a workaround for this?

**Note:** I am using CoreUI React free version and my current version is 3.1.1